# displaying current number of unique users on website using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, web-development-server

I'm trying to display number of current users on a particular page on my website. I got to know about socket.io for doing this exact particular thing but every solution on the internet had a separate server.js file to make it work. My question is, how do I implement this using app.js which I have already configured for my website's use, listening on port 3000. Sorry if my question is a little naive but I've recently started web development and don't know exactly how to do this.

My app.js is as follows:

```
//jshint esversion:6

require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const _ = require('lodash');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

//Passport Sessions setup
app.use(session({
  secret: "Our little secret.",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Users DB
let conn = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb+srv://@cluster0.wrvir.mongodb.net/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
// conn.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  username: String,
  // password:String,
  googleId: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = conn.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  User.findById(id, function(err, user){
    done(err, user);
  });
});

// Google Authentication Strategy
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/timeline",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id, username: profile.displayName }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

// Stories DB
let conn2 = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb+srv://@cluster0.wrvir.mongodb.net/storiesDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String
};

const Post = conn2.model("Post", postSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] })
);

app.get("/auth/google/timeline",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect to timeline.
    res.redirect('/timeline');
  });

app.get("/posts/:postid", function(req, res){
  const requestedPostId = req.params.postid;
  Post.findOne({_id: requestedPostId}, function(err, post){
   res.render("post", {
     title: post.title,
     content: post.content
   });
 });
});

app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose");
});

app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  });

  post.save(function(err){
   if (!err){
     res.redirect("/timeline");
   }
 });
});

app.get("/timeline", function(req, res){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    Post.find({},function(err, posts){
      res.render("timeline", {
        startingContent: homeStartingContent,
        posts: posts
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000...");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Server side

The `app.listen` function at the end of your code returns a `server` object, which can then be used to setup a socket like that:

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');

// ...

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}.`));

const io = socketio(server);
```

Then you could have the following logic to count your users and emit an event to every user, if the count changes:

```
let userCount = 0;

io.on('connection', socket => {
  userCount++;
  io.emit('user-count-change', userCount);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    userCount--;
    io.emit('user-count-change', userCount);
  });
});
```

**Optional**
But since this code would constantly emit events to every user on every connection, the number of emits would grow exponentially. As a solution I'd fire events in an interval with a bit of delay in between:

```
const userCountUpdateDelay = 10000;

let userCount = 0;

io.on('connection', socket => {
  userCount++;
  socket.on('disconnect', () => { userCount--; });

  socket.emit('user-count-change', userCount);
});

setInterval(() => {
  io.emit('user-count-change', userCount);
}, userCountUpdateDelay);
```

## Client side

Add this html somewhere to a your website:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io();

  socket.on('user-count-change', function (userCount) {
    console.log(userCount);
    // Display the user count...
  });
</script>
```

## Learn more

If you wanna learn more about socket.io, it has a great documentation, which you can find [here](https://socket.io/docs)

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work for me. The userCount remains at 0, does not increment. Do I have to do anything else as well for this to work?

Comment: If you've tested your code and it's working fine then maybe I'm doing something wrong at my end. just tell me where do I insert your code exactly in my app.js as I'm unable to make this work properly. Thanks!

Comment: @niranjay_30 Ok I edited my answer and added a client side example. If there are any errors please share them with my, I didnt try that code

Comment: I'm still unable to make it work....Don't know where exactly am I getting this wrong. And thanks for the documentation though I had already gone through that many times.

Comment: No...No errors...I tried console logging but I'm only getting the value of userCount to be equal to zero

Comment: @niranjay_30 Ok, I tried my code and fixed two missing brackets and it works. Are you coding on your phone or why don‘t you see the client side errors?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake on my side by not checking the client side's console log. Thanks for the help. It works!